# How to use environment variable from parent Docker file?

Tags: docker, environment-variables, parameter-passing, environment

I have two Dockerfiles `Dockerfile.A` & `Dockerfile.B` where `Dockerfile.B` inherits using the FROM keyword from `Dockerfile.A`. In `Dockerfile.A` I set an environment variable that I would like to use in `Dockerfile.B` (PATH). Is this possible, and how would I go about doing it?

---

So far I have tried the following in `Dockerfile.A`:

1. ```
   RUN export PATH=/my/new/dir:$PATH
   ```
2. ```
   ENV PATH=/my/new/dir:$PATH
   ```
3. ```
   RUN echo "PATH=/my/new/dir:$PATH" >/etc/profile
   ```

---

And in `Dockerfile.B`, respectively:

1. Just use tools in the path to see if they were available (they were not)
2. ```
   ENV PATH
   ```
3. ```
   RUN source /etc/profile
   ```

---

I realized that every RUN command is executed in it's own environment, and that is probably why the ENV keyword exists, to make it possible to treat environments independently of the RUN commands. But I am not sure what that means for my case.

So how can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Works as expected for me.

Dockerfile.A

```
FROM alpine:3.6
ENV TEST=VALUE
```

Build it.

```
docker build -t imageA .
```

Dockerfile.B

```
FROM imageA
CMD echo $TEST
```

Build it.

```
$ docker build -t imageB .
```

Run it

```
$ docker run -it imageB
VALUE
```

Comment: CMD is not RUN, I want the value at build time, nor tun time!

Comment: I tested your example and it works at build time as well, so there must be some other reason why this does not work for me. Thanks!